# Load a lot of documents in Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongoose, websocket

I want to do client-side filtering of some elements, so I have to load a lot of documents into my webpage - all at once.

I am afraid that it will slow my page too much although it's only 100 documents. Is it possible to make sure the page is not hanging? Can I load the documents in chunks or something? I'm wondering if it makes sense to retrieve the documents as JSON and then use some code to load them in chunks and not let the page hang, but I would rather just retrieve the documents as normal html if it's possible.

I have been inspired from https://github.com/jiren/filter.js where the data is in JSON and the page gets 'filled up' with elements. Would it eventually make sense to load just some of the documents (10 or something) in the template by html and then retrieve the remaining documents with some AJAX or websockets?

Comment: I think generators is just what are you looking for. https://strongloop.com/strongblog/how-to-generators-node-js-yield-use-cases/

Comment: Looks good, but should I then use `socket.io` to ask for new data? Do you know a page that explains how to use it with express in node.js?

Comment: sockets or generators?

Comment: You can just create an Express route for an ajax ajax call that requests a range of documents with start and end range numbers as query parameters.  Then, it's up to you whether you fetch that range from scratch each time or whether you have some sort of cache in the server that makes it more efficient for subsequent requests.  Probably the better solution is to do the filtering server-side rather than client-side.  I don't see any particular reason to involve socket.io here.  This is just a normal client-side ajax call.